# Feeder strategy in Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I just tried implementing the below strategy to feed values from a CSV feeder in Gatling.

1. val csvFeeder = csv("data/Pet1.csv").batch.circular
2. val csvFeeder = csv("data/Pet1.csv").circular

Both seem to work fine. When do we use  ".batch.circular" instead of ".circular" as the feeding strategy in Gatling.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/feeder/#loading-mode) about the differences between default adaptive, `eager` and `batch` feeder loading modes.